# Using 2 background on the same row in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3

I want to create "squares/rectangles" with different background colors. Here is an example of what I want : [image: mockup]

The black vertical lines represent the container that I use. When I apply a background-color to the inner elements, it doesn't "extends" outside the container.

Here is the code :

```
<!-- Header -->
<section class="purple-area">
<div class="container">
        <h1> PURPLE </h1>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Main Content -->
<section class="space-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"> DARK GREY </div>
            <div class="col-md-6"> LIGHT GREY </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: JSfiddle please. but can you not put the bg images on the `body` tag?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kWmDw/ (I didn't include the xs version, make sure your screen works with sm or md size)

Answer (score 0):

Extend the container to the full width and play with the padding of your inner divs.

You can also 'cheat' by defining divs outside of the black container giving them the appropriate background.

Answer (score 0):

This simple example will explain how to make `2 background` in `a single container` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9SP6j/). Hope it helps

--EDIT : [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWmDw/1/)

--[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWmDw/2/) with responsive capabilities

Comment: I know how to do this. What I want is the background-color to extend left and right (so I don't want to have any red background on the sides of the green & blue)

Comment: you cant, you have to let both out of the .container. here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kWmDw/1/ basically combining my answer with your current fiddle

Comment: yes it doesn't because the cols does not own bg color. you can, however, override the design based on the current window width to make it responsive : http://jsfiddle.net/kWmDw/2/ You can configure the media width as you need. This fiddle return the bg color of each cols and hide the bg from .parent if window width is under 480px